# How can I access default colaboratory packages when running on local runtime?

Tags: remote-access, google-colaboratory

Is there a way I can access the default packages on Google Colaboratory when I am running on local runtime. I have connected my colab to a notebook server which is running on a remote server and the packages I need are not installed on that system. (My local runtime is the remote server in this case).

Basically the remote server has the gpu which I need to use apart from the datasets and other files and I want to use the default packages provided by Colab.

Comment: Which package in particular? (Some packages available on Colab can be installed outside of the Colab environment. Others cannot be.)

Comment: I need to install Torch

Comment: Check out the [pytorch docs for local installation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Comment: Well there are a lot of issues of installing pytorch on my local system. This was the main reason I wanted to use Colabs default packages.

Comment: The only way to take advantage of Colab's preconfigured environment is to use Colab managed backends. There's no way to replicate the Colab environment locally without going through the setup process for each package.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification.